# Pattern specific variables to express dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a need to express a pattern rule where the dependencies for the target are defined in a variable name with the pattern. How can I express this?

```
myvar_image1:=a.o b.o c.o d.o
myvar_image2:=f.o g.o h.o i.o j.o

myimage-%: $(myvar_%)
    ld -o $@ $(myvar_$*)
```

Is there way of achieving this?

Comment: Why can't you just express the dependencies normally? I.e. `myimage-image_1: a.o b.o c.o d.o` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, one solution is this:

```
# For testing:
# touch {a..e}.c
# make all
Sources = a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c
# Now $(Objects) = a.o b.o ...
Objects = $(Sources:.c=.o)

%.o: %.c
    @echo "Say hi from $< to $@"

all: $(Objects)
    @echo Say hi $^
```

Once you have the sources, makefile can create the proper extension of the object. Later let make to create each object with the pattern style: `%.o: %.c`